# jQuery "window.location.hash" - getting hash too late?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fragment-identifier, hashchange, browser-state

I'm working on some script but it have a serious problem with hashes.

I have a list of link-images like:

```
<a href="#1"><img src="1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#1"><img src="2.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#1"><img src="3.jpg" /></a>
```

All I want to do is to load file files/#1.html after clicking the first image, files/#2.html after the second etc.

Here's my jQuery function:

```
$("a img").click(
function()
{  
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        $("#displayFile").load('files/'+ hash +'.html');
        $("#displayFile ").fadeIn(300);  
 });
```

So when I click a image it should add hash to the url (href="#1"), load the right file to #displayFile div and fade it in.

But actually when I click the image it shows empty #displayFile div and after i refresh the site with the same hash it loads the content. I believe the script gets the hash long before it's in URL.

How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers run before default actions. Short of nasty tricks involving `setTimeout` you can't get the link to be followed before the function completes.

Read `this.href` instead.

That said, it sounds like you are using arbitrary fragment identifiers instead of URIs to sensible things. If so: I'd fix up the href so it points to a real URL that loads the image. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

Answer (score 2):

When you click the link, code will be executed in the following order:

- jQuery click-handlers
- onclick-handlers
- native/default behavior (calling the link, writing it to window.location)

I would recommend that you use `this.href` instead. Also use `e.preventDefault()` so the native/default behavior isn't performed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default event changing the `location.hash` hasn't happened yet, you can fetch the [`.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a) from the anchor directly instead, like this:

```
$("a img").click(function() {  
  var hash = this.parentNode.hash;
  $("#displayFile").load('files/'+ hash +'.html').fadeIn(300);  
});
```

Though, since the image is the only thing, you can attach the handler to the `<a>` itself, like this:

```
$("a").click(function() { 
  $("#displayFile").load('files/'+ this.hash +'.html').fadeIn(300);  
});
```